# How to shuffle the arrays in for loop manually?

Tags: php, arrays, json, random, shuffle

I'v written 2 codes to shuffle some arrays whitch are in a for loop
First:

```
$numbers = range(0, sizeof($array_id)-1);
shuffle($numbers);
foreach ($numbers as $number) {
$arr = array("user" => array("id" => $array_id[$number], "name" => $array_name[$number], "key" => $array_key[$number]));
}
echo json_encode($arr);
```

This one has a big problem and that's if the `$number` in one of the arrays equals to 5 it won't loop to put another result of `$number` in the that array, for example the result would be something like this:

```
{"user":{"id":["18","2","36"],"name":["alex","john"],"key":["159","228,"486,"852"]]}}
```

All of my arrays have 5 values in them and you can see it returned them defectively.I'll be thankful if anyone can tell me why when `$number` gets the max value in range by shuffle and array gets that `$number` it stocks?

---

Second:

```
function shuffle_assoc(&$array) {
    if (shuffle($array)) { 
        return $array; 
    }else{ 
        return FALSE; 
         } 
    }
for ($y=0; $y<sizeof($array_id); $y++) {
    $arr = array("user" => array("id" => shuffle_assoc($array_id), "name" => shuffle_assoc($array_name), "key" => shuffle_assoc($array_key)));
    }
echo json_encode($arr);
```

This one works fine But I want the `id` and `name` to be match I mean they shuffle the same(**if $array_id[2] then array_name[2]**) that's why I wrote the first code.anyway for this one if anyone knows how to make `id` and `name` shuffle the same I'll be appreciate that.(sorry if I had mistakes in my writing my first language isn't English but I love English :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that I completely understood you, but

```
$numbers = range(0, 5);
// $number = array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

> All of my arrays have 5 values

It's

```
$array_id[0]
$array_id[1]
$array_id[2]
$array_id[3]
$array_id[4]
```

So you haven't $array_id[5]. I think you need `$numbers = range(0, 4);`

EDIT:

Once again, I'm not sure if you want this to happen.

```
<?php
$array_id = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$array_name = array('a','b','c','d','e');
$numbers = range(0, 4);
shuffle($numbers);
$arr = array();
foreach ($numbers as $number) {
$arr["id"][] = $array_id[$number];
$arr["name"][] = $array_name[$number];
}
$arr2 = array("user" => array("id" => $arr["id"], "name" => $arr["name"]));
echo json_encode($arr2);

?>
```

Comment: Excuse me! in my original code for maximum value I wrote size of array minus 1 and here I forgot to write it! now I corrected it.

Comment: OK. Could you write here example of your arrays ($array_id, $array_name, $array_key) and example how final json should look?

Comment: something like this:{"user":{"id":["18","2","36","46","78"],"name":["alex","john","sam","kosta","daniel"],"key":["159","228,"486,"852","573"]]}}

Comment: but each time it loops just the key shuffle randomly and the relation between id and names dont change

Comment: for example if id for alex is 18 and they the arrays shuffle then they position would be the same

Comment: And you don't want same positions, you want shuffling ids and shuffling names separately?

Comment: Separately but in the same algorithm

Comment: if $array_id[2] then array_name[2]

Comment: THAT'S EXACTLY WHAT I WANT THANK YOU SO MUCH I really don't know how to appreciate that.YOUR REALLY REALLY NICE :) unlike many others that just watched.Thank you